# Sql script to Update a table based on multiple conditions using CASE statement

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables under different database( using SQL 2012), Table1 and Table2 and need to update Table1 based on the ID and the value of Table2

Table1:

```
ID      Seen-Date     Disease-Cat
111     01/01/2008    value1
111     01/01/2010    value2
111     03/-5/2-11    value10
222     03/02/2015    value3
```

Table2:

```
ID  Registered-Date   Main-Category            Sub-category

111     01/01/2011    1:Blood Pressure          1.1 Blood Pressure Subcat
111     12/12/2011    1:Blood Pressure          1.2 Blood Pressure Subcat
333     02/02/2015    2:CardioVasular Disease   2.3 CardioVasular Disease Subcat
222     12/04/2013    3:Lung Disease            3.1 Lung Disease
444     01/01/2008    4:Electro cardiogram      NULL
```

Desired output:

```
ID      Seen Date   Value
111     01/01/2008  1.1 BP Subcat
111     01/01/2010  1.1 BP Subcat
111     03/-5/2-11  1.1 BP Subcat
444     03/02/2015  4 ECG
```

**Conditions:**

1. Table2 has more than 1 'Registered Date' and i have to take the latest 'Registered Date' and its corresponding 'Main Category' and 'Sub Category'
   values to update Table1.
2. When the ID matches between 2 tables, Update 'Disease Cat' field based on the value of Table2's 'Main Category' & 'Sub Category'
3. Need to do mapping of disease codes because these 2 tables have different ways of recording the disease codes.

For eg:

```
Table1(Disease Cat)   Table2(Main Category & Sub Category codes) 

1 BP                    1:Blood Pressure  
1.1 BP                  1.1 Blood Pressure Subcat
```

4. When the ID matches, update Table1's 'Disease Cat' field with table2's 'Sub Category' value, and if 'Sub category' is NULL update 'Disease Cat' of Table1 with Table2's 'Main Category' field.

   When i run the following script, it get error as
   'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

   ```
    UPDATE Table1  
    SET Value =   
    (SELECT CASE WHEN [Sub category] IS NULL THEN   
    CASE [Main Category] WHEN '1:Blood Pressure' THEN '1 BP'
                         WHEN '2:CardioVasular Disease' THEN '2 CVD'
                         WHEN '3:Lung Disease' THEN '3 LD'
    END    
    ELSE CASE [Sub category] 
                         WHEN '1.1 Blood Pressure Subcat' THEN '1.1 BP'
                         WHEN '2.3 CardioVasular Disease Subcat' THEN '2.3 CVD'
                         WHEN '3.2 Lung Diasease Subcat' THEN '3.2 LD'
     END
    END
      FROM Table2 D
   WHERE  Table1.nhsnumber = D.nhsnumber )
   ```

Also how to modify this script to get the latest 'Registered Date' date(maximum) from Table2.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of complex update statements because it's simply not worth the added effort to get your logic right.  I'd rather write several simple updates, wrap them in a transaction, and be done with it..